# Calculating a Complicated Integral of Two Variables

Tags: integration, asymptotics, special-functions

I have encountered the following integral
$$I=\int_{0}^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{c_1 + c_2 \cos\theta_2}{-a + \cos\theta_1 + \cos\theta_2} \cos(m\theta_1) \cos(n\theta_2) d\theta_1 d\theta_2$$
where $a>2$ and I am having a hard time moving forward. I would be happy with an analytic solution, converting this to some non-elementary but known special function, or finding the asymptotic behavior of the integral as $a \rightarrow 2$ from the positive reals.

I was able to perform the $\theta_1$ integration by looking in Gradshteyn and Ryzhik and this yields something proportional to
$$\int_{0}^{2\pi}  \frac{c_1 + c_2\cos\theta_{2}}{\sqrt{a^2 - 2 a\cos(\theta_{2})-\sin(\theta_{2})^2}} \cos\left[n\theta_{q'}\right]\\
\times \left(\sqrt{a^2 - 2 a\cos(\theta_{2})-\sin(\theta_{2})^2} -a + \cos(\theta_{2}) \right)^{m}d\theta_{2}.$$
Trying to find this form in a table was hopeless, so I changed variables to $x=\cos\theta_2$. Having to expand $\cos(n\theta_2)$ introduced a sum, and the resulting integral is proportional to
$$\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \frac{c_1 + c_1 x}{\sqrt{\left(-a + x \right)^2 -1 }} \\
\times \left(\sqrt{\left(-a + x\right)^2 -1} -a + x) \right)^{m}\sum\limits_{\substack{r=0 \\ 2r \leq n}} (-1)^r \binom{n}{2r} x^{n-2r} (1-x^2)^r.$$
I am pretty stumped at this point.

I tried doing some further expansions, but I got infinite sums of infinite sums, so this didn't seem like progress (the hypergeometric ${}_{3}F_{2}$ and the regularized ${}_{2}\tilde{F}_{1}$ appeared in this approach).

There are reduction formulas for integrals, but many of them don't seem to apply, as I have two distinct square roots ($\sqrt{1-x^2}$ and $\sqrt{\left(-a + x\right)^2 -1}$). However, my integrand is a rational function of these square roots and $x$.

There is a small parameter in the problem, namely $\epsilon>0$ in $a = 2 +\epsilon$. The integral diverges for $a=2$, so this is a singular perturbation problem (if this approach is even helpful).

I would appreciate any suggestions or advice on this problem!

Comment: At least we have the following asymptotics: $$ \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{d\theta_1 d\theta_2}{a-\cos\theta_1-\cos\theta_2} \sim -2\pi \log \left(\frac{a^2}{4}-1 \right) \qquad \text{as } a \downarrow 2 $$

Comment: @SangchulLee Thanks for this result. What method did you use to find to find it? Watson's lemma or the saddle point approximation don't seem like they will work here, so the only remaining options (that I know of) seem like integration by parts or asymptotic matching. Hopefully your approach can be generalized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extracting the leading order is not hard. Indeed, let $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{C}$ be a continuous function such that $f(k_1, k_2) = f(k_1 + 2\pi, k_2) = f(k_1, k_2 + 2\pi)$ for all $k_1, k_2 \in \mathbb{R}$. Then with $\|f\| = \sup |f|$,

$$ \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{f(k)}{a-\cos k_1 - \cos k_2} \, dk_1 dk_2 
= \int_{B(0,\pi)} \frac{f(k)}{a - 2 + \frac{1}{2}|k|^2} \, dk + \mathcal{O}(\|f\|). $$

Now applying the polar coordinates change followed by the substitution $r=\sqrt{2(a-2)u}$,

\begin{align*}
\int_{B(0,\pi)} \frac{f(k)}{a - 2 + \frac{1}{2}|k|^2} \, dk
& = \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{r}{a-2+\frac{1}{2}r^2} \left( \int_{S^1} f(r\omega) \, d\omega \right) \, dr \\
&= \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi^2}{2(a-2)}} \left( \int_{S^1} f(\omega\sqrt{2(a-2)u}) \, d\omega \right) \,  \frac{du}{u+1} \\
&\sim 2\pi f(0) \log \left( \frac{\pi^2}{2(a-2)} \right) \\
&\sim -2\pi f(0) \log(a-2).
\end{align*}

As an alternative direction, I guess that a probabilistic interpretation may perhaps help analyze the behavior of $I$. Indeed,

$$ G^p(x,y) = \frac{1}{2\pi^2} \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{e^{-ik\cdot y}}{\frac{2}{1-p} - \cos(k_1) - \cos(k_2)} \, dk $$

is the Green function of the 2-D simple random walk on $\mathbb{Z}^2$ killed at rate $p$.